# How to set the password for a new created in bash user using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Need some help in assigning a password to each newly created user from a text file using awk.

For example:

Text file:

```
John Doe 12345678

Jane Doe 87654321

Newly created user:

JDoe5678 with password: 12345678

JDoe4321 with password: 87654321
```

My current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH_EMPLOYEE_FILE="employeelist"
password=($(awk '{print {print $3}))}' "${PATH_EMPLOYEE_FILE}"))
groupname="group1"

USERS_LIST=($(awk '{print substr($1,1,1) $2 substr($3,length($3)-3,length($3))}' "${PATH_EMPLOYEE_FILE}"))

for USER in "${USERS_LIST[@]}"
do
    echo "User account created: ${USER}"
    useradd -m -G "${groupname}" "${USER}" -p ${password}
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what problem you have with your existing code that you'd like help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not indexing `$password`, so you're always using the first password in the `useradd` command.

There's no need for `awk` or arrays, you can use bash's `read` command, and its parameter expansion operators to extract parts of the first name and password into the username.

```
while read -r fname lname password; do
    username=${fname:0:1}$lname${password: -4} # don't forget the space before -4
    echo "User account created: $username"
    useradd -m -G "$groupname" "$username" -p "$password"
done < "$PATH_EMPLOYEE_FILE"
```